# Maven Migration of Legacy EE Application

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee

We are planning on migrating our legacy Java EE application from an ant build to a maven build.  Currently, each of our EJBs has its own META-INF/ejb-jar.xml.

Maven only expects one ejb-jar.xml per EJB module.  So when I build none of these EJBs are identified as needing to go through ejbc.

I'd really prefer not to have to combine all of these ejb-jar.xml's (and also weblogic specific .xml's) down into a single descriptor as there are > 50 and this would cause a hot mess.  I also don't want to break down each of these EJBs down into separate EJB modules as this is also going to cause a small nightmare.

Question: Does anyone know a (hopefully elegant) way to still have maven build all my EJBs with their own ejb-jar.xml other than the two (not elegant) ways above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up just merging them down into a single descriptor manually.  This avoided any weird ant task like solutions as well as shattering the project into hundreds of pieces.  The goal will be to migrate as many beans to EJB 3.0 annotated style as possible as they are touched.

Ran into an interesting issue too where EJB 2.0 ejb-jar.xml caused annotations not to fire.  Simply fixed by updating the now merged descriptor to 3.0.  This exposed on single change on the DTD side having to do with MDBs that was easily fixed with some regular expression replace magic.